# Attribute data showing (Pop-up) in GeoSever

Tags: geoserver, web-gis

How can I show attribute value of shapefile in geodatabase?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OpenStreetMaps and GeoServer</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.css" type="text/css">




<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js'>      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Text</p>



<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
    <script>
    //Defining projections
        var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

    //Defining bounds    
        var world = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -89, 180, 89).transform(
            geographic, mercator
        );
    //Defining map center    
        var lund_center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(92.19,21.63).transform(
            geographic, mercator
        );

        var options = {
            projection: mercator,
            displayProjection: geographic,
            units: "m",
            maxExtent: world,
            maxResolution: 156543.0399,

        };
    //Defining main variables  
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options, { controls: [] });
        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayer(osm);


    //List of layers 
        ///////////////////////////////////////my layer
        var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "CTG_fiber",
            "http://192.168.1.185:8080/geoserver/Fiber/wms",
            {layers: "Fiber:CTG_fiber", 
            transparent: true}
        );
        map.addLayer(tiled);




    //Map center and zoom
        map.setCenter(lund_center, 14);

    //List of controls    
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());          
        map.addControl(new new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());

    //Coordinates of mouse position
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A shapefile cannot be in a geodatabase. They are mutually exclusive file formats.

Comment: maybe what you want is the GetFeatureInfo request?